# Alternatives to verbose-trad?

Tags: miktex

Absolute begginer here.
I am trying to create a decent bibliography in MikTex that allows for citations in the form of footnotes.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=verbose-trad3]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bb}
\begin{document}

Random citation \autocite[1]{primer}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

, where {bb} is my BiBTex database and {primer} is the name of a document.

But I need to cite in APA or Chicago style. However, if I change "verbose-trad2" for "apa", "apa6", "chicago" or "econometrica", the console will report: "! Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style."
Any help?

Comment: Any reason not to use biber as backend? It is much more powerful than bibtex and you can use all the styles.

Comment: Yees there is, I find it much more confusing. I do not know what is going on: if I use biber as a backend and set the style to apa (or whichever for the matter) I recieve the document with no bibliography, and the name of the citation in bold. Not even using the sequence LaTex, Biber, LaTex LateX renders the document. --- I am using MikTex

Comment: Ok, let's try to solve the problem with biber. This document should compile fine with latex, biber, latex, latex: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mvxrzwqwjsbn Can you try and report back? Please include your .log and .blg files

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do apreciate your help. Instead of `\footnote{}` I was writing `\autocite{}`. That solves the problem. However, even though now APA works fine, other styles such as Chicago or Econometrica do not work, even though they are installed. Any idea why?

Comment: For chicago loading with `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}` works fine. I don't know any biblatex style called Econometrica

Comment: thank you so much! I'll figure out the econometrica thing by myself if anything